# How to make transaction atomic in EOS?

Tags: consensus

As we known, if a transaction fails, the results of all actions in the transaction must be rolled back.

For example, account user1 (only has 80 EOS) submit a transaction that do following tasks:

1. Modify multi index table in contract.
2. Transfer 50 EOS from user1 to user2.
3. Transfer 50 EOS from user1 to user3.

This transaction would fail as the balance of user1 is not enough.

How eos rollback the changes for multi index table?

In link https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cpp/docs/communication-model, I find there is a concept of “Current Transaction Data”, but there is no detailed information.

Could someone tell me the technical details about how to make transaction atomic in EOS?

Comment: https://github.com/EOSIO/chainbase/blob/0a347683902f3ebbf58a4dd6166d68d967e240ce/include/chainbase/chainbase.hpp#L313 read this file

Answer (score 2):

Transactions are atomic on EOS and this is done behind the scenes for you. If this wasn't enforced for all transactions on the blockchain, the token would be useless.

The code of the EOSIO copies the values of the needed variables to a temporary area and runs the tasks in the transaction. If any validation fails, e.g. not enough funds in an account, the whole transaction fails and no new data is saved to the main blockchain state.

Comment: In https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/353 , Daniel Larimer said:
We cannot use the traditional approach to "backup data before modifying it" because that would be a sequential process (multiple transactions attempting to do this at the same time would be a mess).